# Change colors for imported images in next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, next.js, next-images

I've created a custom icon and imported it as SVG on my next.js app. I want to implement a feature where users can customize the color of this icon, like red to yellow or black, etc. But this is static image, is there a way I can achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few possible ways to approach this:

- Webpack via `@svgr/webpack`
- Babel via `babel-plugin-inline-react-svg`
- Next.js Image via `Dangerously Allow SVG` in `next.config.js` (Not a recommended approach)

**First off, your SVG image needs to be fillable**. How to do this is beyond the scope of the question, but there are many resources online to help you.

### Applies to each approach below (not repeated for spacing saving)

In the file you want the SVG to show

```js
import Star from './star.svg'

const Example = () => (
  <div>
    // set your color in fill and stroke is optional
    <Star height="100" width="100" fill="#6973ff" stroke="black" />
  </div>
)
```

### Webpack (recommended choice)

I made a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-svg-xufwcm) with this approach on Codesandbox

Snippet code pulled from [react-svgr](https://react-svgr.com/docs/next/)

1. Install `yarn add --dev @svgr/webpack`
2. In the `next.config.js` file add the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    })

    return config
  },
}
```

3. Review *In the file you want the SVG to show* code above

### Babel

Snippet code pulled from [plugin repo](https://github.com/airbnb/babel-plugin-inline-react-svg)

1. `yarn add -D babel-plugin-inline-react-svg`
2. Add following to your `.babelrc` file:

```js
{
  "plugins": [
    "inline-react-svg"
  ]
}
```

3. Review *In the file you want the SVG to show* code above

### Next.js Image (Not recommended)

Excerpt from Next.js as to why you shouldn't use this approach:

> The default loader does not optimize SVG images for a few reasons. First, SVG is a vector format meaning it can be resized losslessly. Second, SVG has many of the same features as HTML/CSS, which can lead to vulnerabilities without proper Content Security Policy (CSP) headers.

Because of what was said from Next.js I won't be coding this example as it's redundant given the other approaches.

If you still want to follow this process you can view their [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#dangerously-allow-svg).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SVGR package(https://react-svgr.com/docs/next/) and convert the SVG to a React component.
And then change the fill with either the fill attribute or style prop.